# Magento Redirection not Working?

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I have been trying to redirect certain CMS pages done earlier now to respective sub-categories but it seems no method is working. I have tried setting up redirects through URL Rewrites and when unsuccessful then using .htaccess file.

The website in question is https://shop.polarisheadsets.com/au/ while the redirects needs to be:

Redirect 301 **/index.php/bluetooth-headsets /headsets/bluetooth-headsets**

Same goes for about 5 more links like above. Basically, **/index.php/bluetooth-headsets** were CMS pages which were used earlier before the Categories and Sub-Categories were designed like they are now. But it seems that no way of redirection is working. I am currently on **Magento 1.9.2**.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add some custom url redirects. I know you tried, but maybe you did it wrong.
You can create the rewrites like this:

Request path `bluetooth-headsets`
Target path `headsets/bluetooth-headsets`
Path Id: `cms-page-bluetooth-headsets` (this is not really important, but it has to be unique)
Redirect: `RP`